# Sum of the Series , Calculus Homework

Tags: calculus

[image: picture]

I put this into WolfRam and got e^(3/5), but I am trying to figure out how to arrive to that answer?

Comment: have some idea for expansion of $e^x$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik not at all. I have no clue how they came up with e in the first place as an answer.

Comment: don't just try evrything in wolfram at first instance...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I agree... Its just the first thing that comes into my head when I see a hard looking question... my mind goes...WOLFRAM

Comment: No No... if you want to "learn"... it should not be the first thing to come to your mind.. though it is on your personal level...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Well said! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know, $$e^x=\sum_{0\le n<\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Here $$\frac{3^n}{5^n\cdot n!}=\frac{\left(\frac35\right)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: very fast reply :)

Comment: looks like the power rule??

Comment: what power rule are you talking about?

Comment: @Christopher, yes( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function).  A closely related series $$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{0\le n<\infty}\frac{x^n}n$$